# From multidimensional array to hierarchy

Tags: python, list, hierarchy

If I am given some data in the following format:

```
data = [
    ['Airbus', 'R&D', '01', 5],
    ['Airbus', 'R&D', '02', 8],
    ['Airbus', 'Marketing', '01', 9],
    ['Airbus', 'Marketing', '02', 54],
    ['Netgear', 'R&D', '01', 12],
    ['Netgear', 'R&D', '02', 5],
    ['Netgear', 'Marketing', '01', 6],
    ['Netgear', 'Marketing', '02', 11],
    ['Toyota', 'R&D', '01', 9],
    ['Toyota', 'R&D', '02', 52],
    ['Toyota', 'Marketing', '01', 43],
    ['Toyota', 'Marketing', '02', 34],
]
```

how can I use python to get a more hierarchical structure, ie:

```
data = {

'Airbus': {
    'R&D': {
        '01': 5, '02': 8
    },
    'Marketing': {
        '01': 9,'02': 54
    }
},
'Netgear'
    etc...
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a bit more flexible with regard to length, but there's no checking for a minimum length record (minimum is 2 elements (key, value).

```
def nest(data):
    result = {}
    for record in data:
        assert len(record) > 2
        d = result
        for key in record[:-2]:
            d = d.setdefault(key, {})

        key,value = record[-2:]
        d[key] = value
    return result
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer, because it allows for N levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Note: This mutates the original data. @NathanBinkert Why do you define your own `defaultdict`?

Comment: @NathanBinkert Your code could be much more simple with `dict.setdefault`. Your while loop already do the "recursivity" job. I'll add it to your answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Also, you can do `record = list(record)` to avoid mutating the original list.

Comment: avoided mutating using a better mechanism (and without copying)

Comment: Doh! You're right.  I can't win.  `for i in xrange(len(record) - 2)`

Comment: You can use `itertools.islice`, but I think the code is ok the way it is. The lists are small and iterators are usually slower in such cases

Answer (score 6):

Quite simple with nested `defaultdict` (or maybe `dict.setdefault` -> less readable):

```
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda:collections.defaultdict(dict))
for x,y,k,v in data:
    d[x][y][k]=v
```

and pretty printing it:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'Airbus': {'Marketing': {'01': 9, '02': 54},
            'R&D': {'01': 5, '02': 8}},
 'Netgear': {'Marketing': {'01': 6, '02': 11},
             'R&D': {'01': 12, '02': 5}},
 'Toyota': {'Marketing': {'01': 43, '02': 34},
            'R&D': {'01': 9, '02': 52}}}
```

Comment: Wow. Very impressive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [autovivification article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python)

```
from collections import defaultdict
def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

d = tree()
for x,y,k,v in data:
    d[x][y][k] = v
```

Comment: if only it was possible to do such assignment `ls[a][b][c]... = x` in arbitrary levels without using `exec` or a loop.

Comment: @JBernado Although this doesn't handle n levels it is imo a better version of your solution

Comment: Sure looks to me like it handles arbitrary levels of nesting. `d = tree(); d[1][2][3][4][5][6] = 7` works fine for me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel arbitrary if you write by hand. If the number `6` was in a variable, how would you do the trick for 6 levels?

Comment: Then we just need one more helper to accept an object and a list of indices, and index into the object iteratively (or recursively). I guess. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).